# Why Ransack performs a query in each loop

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ransack

I search with all members for a special group:

Controller:

```
class Groups::MembersController < ApplicationController

  def index
    @group = Group.find_by_name(params[:groupname])
    @search = @group.members.ransack(params[:q])
    @members = @search.result().includes(:user).page(params[:page]).per(5)
    respond_to do |format|
      format.js
      format.html
    end
  end
  ...
```

Model:

```
class Member < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :group
end
```

View:
Here puts were deposited.

```
...
- puts 'Out'
- @members.each do |member|
  - puts 'In'
  - user = member.user
  - userShow = user_path(user)
  .list-group-item{id: member.id}
  ...
```

Output:

```
Started GET "/groups/Test/members" for 127.0.0.1 at
Processing by Groups::MembersController#index as HTML
  Parameters: {"groupname"=>"Test"}
  Group Load (0.0ms)  SELECT  "groups".* FROM "groups" WHERE "groups"."name" = ? LIMIT ?  [["name", "Test"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  Rendering groups/members/index.html.haml within layouts/application
  Rendered layouts/nav/sidebar/_groups.html.haml (4.0ms)
Out
  Member Load (0.0ms)  SELECT  "members".* FROM "members" WHERE "members"."group_id" = ? LIMIT ? OFFSET ?  [["group_id", 2], ["LIMIT", 5], ["OFFSET", 0]]
  User Load (0.5ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" IN (15, 24, 48, 9, 4)
In
  Member Load (0.0ms)  SELECT  "members".* FROM "members" WHERE "members"."group_id" = ? LIMIT ?  [["group_id", 2], ["LIMIT", 11]]
In
  CACHE Member Load (0.0ms)  SELECT  "members".* FROM "members" WHERE "members"."group_id" = ? LIMIT ?  [["group_id", 2], ["LIMIT", 11]]
In
  CACHE Member Load (0.0ms)  SELECT  "members".* FROM "members" WHERE "members"."group_id" = ? LIMIT ?  [["group_id", 2], ["LIMIT", 11]]
In
  CACHE Member Load (0.0ms)  SELECT  "members".* FROM "members" WHERE "members"."group_id" = ? LIMIT ?  [["group_id", 2], ["LIMIT", 11]]
In
  CACHE Member Load (0.0ms)  SELECT  "members".* FROM "members" WHERE "members"."group_id" = ? LIMIT ?  [["group_id", 2], ["LIMIT", 11]]
  Rendered groups/members/_index_list.html.haml (7068.8ms)
   (0.0ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "members" WHERE "members"."group_id" = ?  [["group_id", 2]]
  Rendered groups/members/index.html.haml within layouts/application (7313.5ms)
  Rendered layouts/_head.html.haml (274.7ms)
  User Load (0.5ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ? ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT ?  [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  Rendered layouts/header/_default.html.haml (7.0ms)
  Rendered layouts/_nav.html.haml (2.0ms)
  Rendered layouts/_flash.html.haml (14.0ms)
Completed 200 OK in 7965ms (Views: 7931.9ms | ActiveRecord: 1.0ms)
```

I do not understand why a query is executed here in each loop. 
Even if done with CACHE, it costs me performance.
Can I fix it?

Comment: How does `CACHE Member Load (0.0ms)` cost you performance?  The log shows you it take `0.0ms` seconds from cache.  The query output shows what SQL would run if it were not cached already.

Comment: `Completed 200 OK in 7965ms (Views: 7931.9ms | ActiveRecord: 1.0ms)
` shows you that the performance slow down is not in active record but in your view.  Can you post the whole of your view and your layout?  When running in development without precompiled assets, your views will render more slowly.  Also HAML can be slow.  Try SLIM or regular ERB.

Comment: correct 0ms is not the problem. why does the same query run every time. the performance only in this mask is bad with every loop

Comment: agree with @lacostenycoder cached queries are not the problem

Answer (score 1):

I think you're mistaken about where the delay is.  Instrument your code with some timestamps and post what happens:

```
- puts "before loop: #{Time.now.to_s(:utc)}"
- puts 'Out'
- @members.each do |member|
  - puts "In loop  #{Time.now.to_s(:utc)}"
  - user = member.user
    - puts "after member.user call  #{Time.now.to_s(:utc)}"
  - userShow = user_path(user)
  .list-group-item{id: member.id}
- puts "End loop  #{Time.now.to_s(:utc)}"
```